# Why is there no download dSYM button in Testflight for my app?

Tags: ios, xcode, testflight

If I navigate to the Build Metadata section for my app within App Store Connect then the Includes Symbols section just says Yes, there is no blue Download dSYM button there.

The XCode build build options Debug Information Format is set to DWARF with dSYM.

So why is there no dSYM on App Store Connect?

Comment: @ObjectiveD Apple is looking into the issue. See: https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/700051?answerId=704176022#704176022

Comment: Last answer on the forum says "I submitted a ticket to Feedback assistant, and someone replied yesterday that the issue had been resolved. I guess we'll find out on the next submission."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apple responded and said they are looking into the issue:

> Thanks for letting us know! Our teams are looking into this. To stay updated on the progress and help with the investigation, please be sure to file a feedback report or contact support directly.

ASC Doesn't generate DSYM file - https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/700051?answerId=704176022#704176022

Answer (score 0):

In my case the dSYM download link suddenly popped up five days after upload. The migration to the new submission system seems to cause massive delays at the moment.